# Create WIFI access point in 14.04 with bridge mode

Tags: 14.04, networking, network-manager, dhcp

Currently i am creating wifi access point using Unity’s default Network Manager IPV4 settings `Shared to other computer` and finally edited the file `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/wifi-hotspot` to change `MODE= ap`,
but i want to use untangle to put captive portal on this AP.

Now the problem in current setup is untangle internal network address is `192.168.5.100`. My ubuntu machine's interface `eth0` has `192.168.5.101`. 
My WIFI access point auto selects access point network ip `10.42.0.1/24`. When device "A" connected with ip 10.42.0.10, untangle shows that the connection come from 192.168.5.101. When device "B" connected with ip `10.42.0.11`, untanle shows that the connection comes from `192.168.5.101`. How can i configure in such way so that i can get `10.42.0.10` and `10.42.0.11` in untangle screen.

Or Wifi access point allot ip to mobile device from the untangle dhcp eg `192.168.5.X` so that untangle can identify the connection source.